# How to rotate triangle animation in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I've been at this for quite a while trying to construct a program which takes a triangle polygon element and infinitely spins it clock-wise. The issue that I'm now facing is a rangeError: maximum call stack exceeded, and I haven't a clue on how to code this in a more practical way. Here's my code with comments included.

```js
var _poly = document.getElementById('pol'); //triangular polygon element

var y1 = 0; // y coordinates for each point of _poly.
var y2 = 375;
var y3 = 375;

var xPTS = [];
/*the following for loop pushes corresponding x coordinates 
                  for each y coordinate into this variable.*/

for (var i = 0; i < _poly.animatedPoints.length; i++) {

  xPTS.push(_poly.animatedPoints[i].x);

}

/*The purpose of the following return function `xVar` is to assign the 
appropriate value for x to each of their respective y coordinates. Each x 
variable will switch from one return function to the other as they cross 
each verticle halves of the svg element.*/
var xVar = function(x, y) {

  if (x >= 250 && y !== 500) {

    return () => {

      return (Math.sqrt(62500 - Math.pow(y - 250, 2)) + 250).toString() + ",";

    };

  } else {

    return () => {

      return (250 - Math.sqrt(62500 - Math.pow(y - 250, 2))).toString() + ",";

    };

  }

};

/*variables `x1`, `x2`, and `x3` are assigned to appropriate values as per 
the y argument in function `xVar`.*/
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

  window["x" + (i + 1).toString()] = xVar(xPTS[i], window["y" + (i + 1).toString()]);

}

/*`coordF` when constantly invoked in `tFunc` is meant to constantly update 
and keep track of the polygon element's x,y coordinates.*/
var coordF = function() {

  coords = [_poly.animatedPoints[0].x.toString() + "," +
    _poly.animatedPoints[0].y.toString() + " ",
    _poly.animatedPoints[1].x.toString() + "," +
    _poly.animatedPoints[1].y.toString() + " ",
    _poly.animatedPoints[2].x.toString() + "," +
    _poly.animatedPoints[2].y.toString()
  ];

}
coordF(); //invoked so coords is accessible. 

//main function
var tFunc = function(x, y, c) {

  /*`ticks` is assigned on the condition evaluated for verifying which 
        verticle half a point of the polygon is located.*/
  ticks = (x >= 250 && y !== 500) ? function(_x, _y) {
    /*note: this is 
                                                   where the error incurs*/

    /*each point is meant to travel x2 as fast as from ranges 0-125 and 375-500 down and up the y-axis when each y coordinate is in the following range: 125-375 so as for the polygon to remain an equilateral triangle.*/
    if (_y >= 125 && _y <= 375) {

      _y += 2;
      return _x() + _y.toString();

    } else {

      _y += 1;
      return _x() + _y.toString();

    }

  } : function(_x, _y) {

    if (_y >= 125 && _y <= 375) {

      _y -= 2;
      return _x() + _y.toString();

    } else {

      _y -= 1;
      return _x() + y.toString();

    }

  };

  tick_tocks = setInterval(function() {

    /*`coords` is constantly updated so as to utilize each item of `coords` as an argument for c so `_poly`'s `points` attribute can constantly be assigned the value to render the triangular polygon element equilateral as it spins.*/
    coordF();

    //`c` argument is evaluated to verify which item of the `coords` array is passed.
    switch (c) {

      /*As each y coordinate changes via `ticks` function, each x coordinate changes correspondingly*/
      case c[0]:
        _poly.setAttribute("points", ticks(x1, y1) + " " + c[1] + c[2]);
        break;

      case c[1]:
        _poly.setAttribute("points", c[0] + ticks(x2, y2) + " " + c[2]);
        break;

      case c[2]:
        _poly.setAttribute("points", c[0] + c[1] + ticks(x3, y3));

    }

  }, 100);

  //alternate functions are assigned when the following boolean expression is true.
  if (y === 0 || y === 500) {

    clearInterval(tick_tocks);

    //x variables are assigned to alternate functions defined in `xVar`.
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

      window["x" + (i + 1).toString()] =
        xVar(xPTS[i], window["y" + (i + 1).toString()]);

    }

    /*`tFunc` is invoked 3 times with 3 different sets of arguments. `x` is the x coordinate, `y` is the y coordinate, and `c` is an item of the `coords` array.*/
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

      tFunc(window["x" + (i + 1).toString()], window["y" + (i + 1).toString()], coords[i]);

    }

  }

};

/*`tFunc` is invoked 3 times with 3 different sets of arguments. `x` is the x coordinate, `y` is the y coordinate, and `c` is an item of the `coords` array.*/
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

  tFunc(window["x" + (i + 1).toString()], window["y" + (i + 1).toString()], coords[i]);

}
```

```html
<svg width=500 height=500 style="border:1px solid black;display:block;margin:auto;">
    <polygon id="pol" stroke="black" stroke-width=3 fill="green" points="250,0 466.50635094610965,375 33.49364905389035,375"/>
</svg>
```

I'm still pretty mediocre with js, but hopefully, I'd appreciate any answers as to why I'm receiving a rangeError notifying at `ticks` in the console, how I can modify the above code to accomplish the task of putting the triangle on an infinite spin, and or a more practical way of accomplishing this task.

Comment: It's perfectly valid to do the math for the rotation in JS as an exercise if you feel like it, but if your goal is the end result and not the exercise itself, you should definitely save yourself some trouble and use [the 'transform' attribute of svg elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform) to rotate your polygon. This can be done either with JS similar to what you're trying to do (but much simpler), or, if you want to do it even simpler, with [CSS animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need a non js solution then you might try rotating it via css3 `transform` property along with usage of `animation, @keyframe` etc. :

```css
#triangle{
  animation: polyRotation 8s linear infinite;
}


@keyframes polyRotation {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<svg id="triangle" width=500 height=500 style="border:1px solid black;display:block;margin:auto;">
    <polygon id="pol" stroke="black" stroke-width=3 fill="green" points="250,0 466.50635094610965,375 33.49364905389035,375"/>
</svg>
```